# Internet Explorer Cannot display the webpage when starting a silverlight app

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, iis-7.5, database-connection

I have a strange problem setting up my webapplications. I have a clean webserver machine where I have two web applications. One is a asp.net application while the other is a silverlight application. Both should use the same database hosted on an external db server.

My problem is that while my asp.net application is working as it should my silerlight application is not even loaded. Loads for about a minute (No silverlight loading indicator) before I get the Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage with following information:

•Internet connectivity has been lost.
•The website is temporarily unavailable.
•The Domain Name Server (DNS) is not reachable.
•The Domain Name Server (DNS) does not have a listing for the website's domain.
•There might be a typing error in the address.
•If this is an HTTPS (secure) address, click Tools, click Internet Options, click Advanced, and check to be sure the SSL and TLS protocols are enabled under the security section.

If I change my connectionstring in web.config for the silverlight application to connect to the test db server (also external) it works fine.

This tells me that the applications should be configured correctly?

connectionstring : `<add name="myConn" connectionString="Data Source=prod_server;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myusername;Password=mysecretpassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

They are running in the same application pool. I have also tried setting them up in separate applicationpools with no luck.

Fiddler reports an 504 error, but why does my web application work? This IIS 7.5

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Was a db update that timed out. Some developers should learn to use logging!